Query String URLs for CodeIgnitor 4
I WANT to show the query string for my CodeIgnitor 4 app.  In CI3 we had Config directives like $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;.
In CI4 we have public string $uriProtocol = 'PATH_INFO'; or public string $uriProtocol = 'QUERY_STRING';.  This impacts how the ROUTES are configured in Config\Routes.php; but, no matter how I build the route, it still just gives me the URL path to the controller.

Please can you provide some code as an example. That will help people answer what the issue might be.

What code would you like to see?  I believe this is a framework configuration issue, not something related to a Controller, Model or View within my application.

What are you trying to achieve with this query string?

I would like to have the query in the URL, so that people can share their search results from my application.  Right now, the 'results URL' is just /search (the name of the Controller.)  And if they share THAT, it just gives them an empty search form (or sometimes an error because the search form was never filled out, and therefore the Controller is sending NULL values to the Model.)
